# Eclipse default with plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

I am trying to create a default Eclipse , with all the plugins installed. So that my team always the same eclipse version , and don't have to installed any extra plugins.

Any idea , where I would have to make changes in order to default eclipse with such settings.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Well, you could install the plugins and zip again. What I do not know is how to prevent additional plugins if you want that too.

Answer (score 1):

Assumig "with all the plugins" you mean all of eclipses official plugins: Go To `Help->Install New Software`, select the Eclipse Update Site (for example `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno`) and install the plugins you need.

If you need other non-official plugins, just install them.

After that you can just zip the eclipse install folder again and distribute it

Answer (score 1):

You can look at creating a "Shared install".  This means that you create an Eclipse installation in a read-only location on a shared drive that all devs have executable and read access to.  Then, when a dev launches the Eclipse instance, a custom configuration area is created in the user's `~/.eclipse` folder.

This works fairly well.  And end users can install their own plugins on top of the base install without affecting others.  The only limitation that I am aware of is that some plugins cannot be installed unless the user has write access to the target install folder (Groovy-Eclipse is one example of this because of its use of a feature patch).

More information on shared installs can be found in [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html).